# Can I trigger the OS to load a page asynchronously with Memory Mapping Files?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-mapped-files

My understanding is the OS will load a page from the Memory Mapped File whenever I request a virtual memory address not yet loaded into the memory. The problem with that it can have up to 4-5 milliseconds to seek to the data on the HDD and I guess my memory request will hang up until then. So I thought when I know I'll need some data soon I can send a request to load that page into memory/cache in advance.

As a naive method I can simply read the memory and then the OS will start to load/cache the page, but when I make a memory read into the Memory Mapped File then my process will hang up until the data arrives. That again will mean a big delay to me.

So the question is if there is a way to just tell the memory manager to prepare to have that data but don't hang me up until the first byte arrives? And when in a few milliseconds later I'll need the data then it will read from the loaded page.

If the answer is OS specific then I'd be interested in OSX and Win.

Comment: Which OS is your target?

Comment: You could create a thread and have that thread do the memory access while you main thread keeps working.

Comment: Yeah I also had the creat thread idea, but thought maybe there is a direct way what is not a workaround.